# How to get root category using store id in magento 2 block file?

Tags: magento2, blocks, store-id

How to get root category using store id.
we get store id using `$storeId = $this->getStoreId();`
We use below code for get root category using store id; but we get wrong.

```
$rootCat = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
```

Any one help us for solve this.

Comment: No; we want store root category; which is assign in 'Store > Setting > All store > Here select any store > you show 'Root Category'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` class to get store default root category Id.

```
<?php
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManagerInterface;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $StoreManagerInterface)
    {
         $this->storeManagerInterface = $StoreManagerInterface;
    }



    public function getRootCategoryId()
    {
        $store = 1;
        return $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore($store)->getRootCategoryId();
    }

}
```

Comment: We use it but not work for me

Comment: what problem you are facing

Comment: Admin side page break; get error page can't reach. Not generate any error in log file.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this

```php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Block;

class MyModel extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Get root category id for current store
     *
     * @return  int
     */

    public function getRootCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore($this->getStoreId())->getRootCategoryId();
        // or return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    }
}
```

So in your block template phtml you will use

```
$block->getRootCategoryId();
```

Comment: Page break in admin; page show 'This page isn’t working'.